# Js Animate doesn't work properly with IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, jquery-animate

I try to animate some changes in css properties.
The idea is to change the size of a box when you click on it (the box is actually a div)

It works fine with Chrome & IE 7,9,10, but there is a problem in the animation when I use IE8.

When the size of one div is increased, the others are translated. Each div contains a letter in plain text. When the div is translated, the same thing happens to the letter contained in this div.

But with IE8, if the translation of the letters are fluid, it is not the case for the divs.

The result is that the div doesn't translate correctly (in a fluid way) but the text does.

This problem doesn't happen with IE7 or 9, only with IE8.

What would you suggest about it ?

HERE is a fiddle I have created.
It is simplified.
Try to click on the boxes to have a better idea, my explanation can be a little confuse.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jG53Z/

```
var idPreviousClick = 1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var int;
    $('.answerDiv').click(function () {
        if (idPreviousClick === $(this)[0].id) {
            alert
        } else {
            for (int = 0; int < 3; int++) {
                $("#" + (int + 1)).css({
                    height: '100',
                    width: '100',
                    top: '0',
                    'line-height': '100px'
                });
            }
            $("#" + ($(this)[0].id)).animate({
                height: '120',
                width: '120',
                top: '-10',
                'line-height': '120px'
            });
            idPreviousClick = $(this)[0].id;
        }
    });

});
```

If you can have an idea concerning why the effect isn't correctly produced in this particular IE8 version.

Thank you,
Tim

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on IE8 (emulated): http://jsfiddle.net/jG53Z/show/

Comment: @A.Wolff confirming that it does work in ie8

Comment: Oh you are right. I do not use Css3 Pie in the fiddle so I removed it from my code and I do not have my problem anymore ( but from an other hand, I do not have the radius and other css properties I was able to use because of CSS3PIE ). Thank you for showing me the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSSPIE makes the animation particularly slow, especially with IE8.
I avoid it, because I need this animation, but will instead use jquery.corner.js, wich offers me the corners I need and a fluid animation.

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

You can also see in this page how to build the border.
AND you can just use the border radius with this script, if the browser support it.